# print part of file name in the middle

Tags: filenames

I have several files with names as:

```
ID_Italy.txt
ID2_USA.txt
ID3_Germany.txt
.....
```

if I want to print before the _ I can do:

```
for file in *.txt; do print "${file%_*}";done
```

Output:

```
ID
ID2
ID3
```

If I want print and remove the extension:

```
for file in *.txt; do print "${file%.*}";done
```

Output:

```
ID_Italy
ID2_USA
ID3_Germany
```

However, I would like to take only whatever is in between _ and . and have the following output:

```
Italy
USA
Germany
```

How to print that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using zsh (which support nested parameter substitution) unlike Bash, you can do:

```
for file in ./*.txt; do
    print "${${file%.txt}#*_}"
done
```

Or otherwise using an array solution in Bash:

```
for file in ./*.txt; do
    { IFS='_.' arr=( $file ); printf "%s\n" "${arr[2]}"; }
done
```

Comment: Note that if the name contains several `_`-delimited substrings, the bash solution would always return the second: `A_B_C_Germany.txt` --> `B`.

Comment: @they based on the question they _"would like to take only whatever is in between `_` and `.` "_ and I answered the question; in case of `A_B_C_Germany.txt` what should be between `_` and `.`? `B_C_Germany`? or `C_Germany` or `Germany`? if you need to get clarification from asker, please ask there not me and I will update my answer then if they wanted some other things.

Comment: you are right, so basically it will return B_C_Germany in the first case...I only have one _, guess in that case then saving to temporary variables is better, thanks

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini it would be nice to mention that clarifying that how is your fileName format is in your question. using single `#` will cut shortest match from the beginning of the file name, while double `##` will cut longest match.

Comment: ok, by the way, I tried this syntax on my laptop with unix and it ok, but on a public server was not working, however "${file%%.*}" works on the server

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini please read the answer carefully: this is for the `zsh` shell. When you say you tried with Unix, I suspect you mean you tried with macOS which uses `zsh` by default. Many other systems use `bash` by default so this won't work there unless you manually run `zsh` first.

Comment: I understand, got it, yes I tried with macOs but the server uses bash, then on the server I have to use the array solution in bash as you suggested, thanks

Comment: The bash script uses "##" and so will remove the maximum string: ID2_ID99_USA.txt returns USA.

Answer (score 5):

Edited, without tempvar:

```
$ for file in *.txt; do echo "${file//?(.*|*_)/}";done
USA
Germany
Italy
```

Comment: you need to explictly enable `extglob`

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
  for f in *.txt ; do
  f="${f%.*}"
  echo ${f##*_}
done
```

I created the files with a `touch` command and then ran the `fx` script:

```
$ touch ID_Italy.txt
$ touch ID2_USA.txt
$ touch ID3_Germany.txt
$./fx
USA
Germany
Italy
```

Comment: sorry, I have several files with that names, I do not want to save part of the name in a variable and then print the other part, I would like to to all together ...any way?

Comment: I think that's covered, I've slightly modified the description to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `basename` utility to remove the filename suffix and a variable substitution for removing the bit of the name up to the last underscore:

```bsh
for name in *_*.txt; do
    basename "${name##*_}" .txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`bash`:

```bsh
for f in ID[0-9_]*[A-Za-z].txt
do
    [[ "$f" =~ _([^.]+) ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

---

standard `POSIX` `sh`:

```bsh
for f in ID[0-9_]*[A-Za-z].txt
do IFS='_'; set -- $f; printf "%s\n" "${2%.*}"
done
```